# Running windows under virtual box for software development - performance issues?

Tags: windows, virtualization

So I have a question about what system I should use to do some C# development. In my course this year at least half of my courses require me to be using Windows specific programs i.e visio, MSSQL, C# etc. I know there are alternatives but I would like to stick to these. I'm wondering about two choices and wanted to know what people could suggest - I am more concerned with performance issues. I have a Macbook Pro and I could run windows 7 on it under virtualbox where I could give it 4gb of ram. Remember I would need windows open a lot with potentially multiple programs running. I also have a desktop gaming rig from a year ago which is much more grunty and am contemplating just using that instead where I could run windows natively. I would prefer to use the mac, but really what I wanted to know is if anyone else uses windows under vb with 4gb of ram dedicated to it with no performance issues?

Comment: What about dual boot?

Comment: if I am going to do that I may as well use desktop

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type development do you want to do ?  If you will develop desktop,web,console application 4gb ram will work fine for you but if you develop mobile projects or games it will be a problem future times. I have co-worker friend who using MacBook Air and developing C# programs he is using two OS one of them is orginal MacBook OS other one W8 if you have 2 section HDD you can create another OS on your notebook. I think best solution for this stuiation is setup Windows 8 to your computer.